# Grabbing Data from 2 different tables at once without a join php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm making a table where I want to show the 4 data fields, 3 from one table and 1 from another table. I have tried using a union and a few other methods and it does not seem to work. The whole code is given below. A screenshot of the 2 tables I'm trying to get data from is also given below.

[image: Table Schema]

Tables: http://gyazo.com/a0839ffc4f5c9cb51458b2b01006c745

What I've been trying(sql not php code):

`SELECT FirstName, LastName, Rating FROM guest WHERE Rating = 5 UNION ALL SELECT Suburb FROM suburb WHERE Suburb = 'Booragoon';`

This is the PHP code :

```
<?php
    echo "<table style = 'border; solid 1px black;'>"
    echo "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Suburb</th><th>Rating</th></tr>";
    class TableRows extends RecursiveInteratorInterator {
        function __construct($it) {
            parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
            }
        function current() {
            return "<td style='width:160px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::curren(). "</td>";
        }
        function beginChildren(){
        echo "<tr>";
        }
        function endChildren() {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
        }
    }
    $Suburb = $_POST['InputSuburb'];
    $Rating = $_POST['InputRating'];
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pizza_shop' $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare//where the command is going
    $stmt->bindParam('Suburb',$Suburb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: you dont have same number of columns in both queries. why you want it without join ?

Comment: @Ameya Deshpande would that not ruin the structure ? if not i would be happy to use a join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a simple join condition on postcode and the where condition what you want to.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Rating,subrup FROM guest inner join suburb 
on guest.postcodefk = suburb.postcode
WHERE Suburb = 'Booragoon' and Rating = 5;
```